# Solrj indexing mechanism

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a question about indexing mechanism using Solr in Java. If I create a documents and i want to find only field "name", solr will be index all fields? Or only index by field "name" in each document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tell Solr to only store the field `name` in your schema, then only the field `name` will be stored.

If you instruct Solr to store everything you send to it (like in the schemaless mode) and you send 400 fields, each of those fields will be stored.

If you want to *store* information but not search for it, only those fields which you are going to query need to be indexed, while the other fields can be limited to just `stored`. If you don't need the content of the field, but just want to search for it, you can set `stored` to false, and `indexed` to true.

Comment: How can i do this, in Java? i cant find any function like, setStored.

Comment: You don't do that in Java. You do it when configuring Solr, either through the `schema.xml` / `managed-schema` under your Solr installation (in the configuration directory for your core), in its location under Zookeeper (if running as a cluster) or through the [SchemaAPI](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html).

Comment: its possible to configure Solr from java?

Comment: In that case you'll be using the SchemaAPI as I linked in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the schema.xml where you define the fields getting used, you need to mention indexed=true for all the fields you want to search on.

In your case it would look something like this -

`<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />`