# Solrj change type from long to string

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a problem with querying in Solrj. I created documents where each document have String fields and Long fields.

For example:

Various: PLZ - type: String

```
     doc.addField("plz",tmp.getPlz());
```

I add this to each document, but Solr is saving this various into long. Why? And how can I change it? Ps. PLZ in will be always a number, like 6868

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [define the field type](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/field-type-definitions-and-properties.html) for each field name in the schema for your collection or core. You do this in the same way [as your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362232/solrj-indexing-mechanism) about schemas.

If you want to tell Solr to use a specific type for a specific field, first you'll have to define the type (inside `<types> .. </types>` in `schema.xml`):

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
```

and then you use that type in the field definition:

```
<field name="description" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
```

.. adjusting the `indexed`/`stored` properties as you need to.

If you want a long field, define the field as the long/integer type valid for your version of Solr.